# Get size of an array of strings in PSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm having some difficulty using the `array_length` function in psql.

I have a json object that looks like this when a call a function named `test_function`:

```
{
    "outer": [
        {
            "keys": {
                "id": 5
            },
            "name": "Joe Bloggs",
            "age": "16",
            "new_rels": [
                "a6h922ao-621y-230p-52bk-t6i84rr3vo6g"
            ],
            "old_rels": [
                "9c8b67bf-871e-4004-88be-9a68dae3a86f",
                "e6a15929-4aab-4af6-903a-8f8c09bef572"
            ],
            "s_id": 1
        }
    ],
    "total": 0,
}
```

I am trying to get the length of `new_rels` and `old_rels` but having some difficulty, possibly due to it being an array of strings.

I have tried this:

```
select array_length(r->'updates'->0->>'new_rels',1)::bigint from test_function(1) r
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
```

I've even tried simplifying it and doing something like this but it doesn't work with the double quotes - if I change manually to single quotes it does word:

```
select array_length('["90faa4b9-23fe-4bde-81e7-4326e7356cde", "d642157c-8a55-44de-ac88-ddaa3ab02bb0"]',1);
```

Comment: `array_length` is for native arrays.  Within `jsonb` or `json` objects, you need to use `json[b]_array_length()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `jsonb_array_length()` function for `jsonb` data.  The `array_length()` function is for native arrays such as `text[]`.

```
with invars as (
  select '{
    "outer": [
        {
            "keys": {
                "id": 5
            },
            "name": "Joe Bloggs",
            "age": "16",
            "new_rels": [
                "a6h922ao-621y-230p-52bk-t6i84rr3vo6g"
            ],
            "old_rels": [
                "9c8b67bf-871e-4004-88be-9a68dae3a86f",
                "e6a15929-4aab-4af6-903a-8f8c09bef572"
            ],
            "s_id": 1
        }
    ],
    "total": 0
}'::jsonb as r
)
select jsonb_array_length(r->'outer'->0->'new_rels'), 
       jsonb_array_length(r->'outer'->0->'old_rels') 
  from invars;

 jsonb_array_length | jsonb_array_length 
--------------------+--------------------
                  1 |                  2
(1 row)
```

Also, you had an extra comma after the `total` key.